# Android toolbar with padding and menu option

Tags: android

How to create a toolbar with left drawer icon,right menu items and having search view similar to play store and attached screen and having the padding. The issue i am facing is with the padding of toolbar, the toolbar is always attached to corners.

xml code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"><!--scroll|exitUntilCollapsed-->


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frg_searcheader"
            class="com.vconnect.store.ui.fragment.searchpage.HomePageHeaderPagerFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/dark_gray"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

[Play store screen]

[image]

Comment: it would be great if you could share the toolbar/xml code that you've written so far.

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: Please share your layout xml code, as @AshishRanjan said

Comment: IMHO that's not a toolbar, but rather a custom widget.

Comment: added xml code @AshishRanjan

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get something close to this using the support library with NoActionBar style:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_bkgd"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

toolbar_bkgd.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetBottom="8dp"
    android:insetLeft="8dp"
    android:insetRight="8dp"
    android:insetTop="8dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
    </shape>

</inset>
```

To get that nice shadow look that Google Play has, you would need to use a nine-patch for the background.